# Python - Convert and filter structured text into object

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, data-structures

**Current problem.**
I'm working with set of data files, which, essentially, look like this:

```
{39107,
    {31685,
        {   f24c4ec6-1e59-47a0-9736-8c823eda0d28,
            "N",
            7
        },
        {   c71dce36-4295-49e4-be03-7c60969b96c3,
            "A",
            8
        },
        {   f80fce14-f001-4b20-84d5-7a00f0788f6b,
            "A",
            9
        },
    }
}
```

And

```
{0,
    {4659,
        {
                        7c90ea6a-12f5-4c54-bfe0-e38120a6e364,
                        "fieldname27472",
                        "N",
                        27472,
                        "",
                        {3,
                                {"field1",
                                        0,
                                        {1,
                                                {
                                                        "B",
                                                        16,
                                                        0,
                                                        "",
                                                        0
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "",
                                        0
                                },
                                {"field2",
                                        0,
                                        {1,
                                                {
                                                "T",
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                "",
                                                0}
                                        },
                                        "",
                                        0
                                },
                                {"field3",
                                        0,
                                        {1,
                                                {
                                                        "L",
                                                        0,
                                                        0,
                                                        "",
                                                        0
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "",
                                        0
                                },
                        },
                        {0},
                        {1,
                                {
                                        edcba,
                                        "ByID",
                                        abcde,
                                        1,
                                        {1,
                                                "ID"
                                        },
                                        1,
                                        0,
                                        0
                                }
                        },
                        1,
                        "S",
                        {0},
                        {0},
                        "",
                        0,
                        0
                }
        }
}
```

Numbers before sets of data, eg 4659 represents number of following data containers.
Some values are not encased in quotes, like uuid in this example, or random strings.

My goal is to convert this data structures in python objects, like lists or tuples, then convert them to JSON for external processing.

Right now i have a 2-stage process.
Stage1 does initial conversion and data evaluation.
Stage2 filters data, removing excessive values (like number of elements before actual elements), and nested lists.

```py
import json

file = 'stack1.json'

def stage1(msg):
    buffer = ''
    st,fh,delim,encase = '[',']',',', '"'
    msg = msg.translate(str.maketrans('{}',st+fh)).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', '')
    while True:
        fhpos = msg.find(fh)
        if fhpos >= 0:
            head = msg[:fhpos+1]
            if head:
                stpos = head.rfind(st)
                if stpos>=0:
                    teststring = head[stpos+1:fhpos].split(delim)
                    for idx,sent in enumerate(teststring):
                        if not (sent.startswith(encase) or sent.endswith(encase)) or sent.count('-') == 4:
                            teststring[idx] = (f'"{teststring[idx]}"')
                            break
                    buffer+= head[:stpos+1]+','.join(teststring)+fh
                else: buffer+=fh
            msg = msg[fhpos+1:]
        else:
            break
    return buffer

def stage2(lst):
    if not any([isinstance(i,list) for i in lst]):
        return tuple(lst)
    if not isinstance(lst[0],list) and all([isinstance(j,list) for j in lst[1:]]):
        lst = stage2(lst[1:])
        if all([isinstance(j,(list,tuple)) for j in lst]) and len(lst) == 1:
            lst, = lst
    for idx,i in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(i,list):
            lst[idx] = stage2(i)
        else:
            continue
    return stage2(lst)

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    try:
        s1 = stage1(data)
        print("STAGE1\n",s1)
        s2 = stage2(json.loads(s1))
        print("STAGE2\n",json.dumps(s2, indent=2))
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

**Current results**:

Example1:

```
STAGE1
[39107,[31685,["f24c4ec6-1e59-47a0-9736-8c823eda0d28","N",7],["c71dce36-4295-49e4-be03-7c60969b96c3","A",8],["f80fce14-f001-4b20-84d5-7a00f0788f6b","A",9]]]
STAGE2
 [
  [
    "f24c4ec6-1e59-47a0-9736-8c823eda0d28",
    "N",
    7
  ],
  [
    "c71dce36-4295-49e4-be03-7c60969b96c3",
    "A",
    8
  ],
  [
    "f80fce14-f001-4b20-84d5-7a00f0788f6b",
    "A",
    9
  ]
]
```

Example2:

```
STAGE1
[0,[4659,[7c90ea6a-12f5-4c54-bfe0-e38120a6e364,"fieldname27472","N",27472,"",[3,[aa-aa-a-a-a,"field1",0,[1,["B","16",0,"",0]]],["field2",0,[1,["T","0",0,"",0]]],["field3",0,[1,["L","0",0,"",0]]]],["0"],[1,[edcba,"ByID",abcde,1,["1","ID"]]],1,"S",["0"],["0"]]]]
STAGE2
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 12 (char 11)
```

Example 2 failed because not all values got quotes.

What libs might be suitable for this case?
Datasets are rather big, currently first example is ~5M chars, stage1 takes up to 1 minute to process.

**Future problem:**
What are the best approaches for converting and filtering data like this?
I think converting AND filtering at the same pass is faster, rather than perform full scan several times.
I've read about [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) and [PEG](https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/), but i don't think this are the right tools for the job.

Comment: have you tried regex on it?

Comment: Well, i thought about it, but didn't came up with right implementation. And i think data is too big for using regexp. I may be wrong

Comment: out of curiosity, how large is it in megabytes?

Comment: Not realy big, around 4 to 5, but total number of files ~49000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to convert this data structures in python objects, like lists or tuples, then convert them to JSON for external processing.

I would actually first convert the string to valid JSON. Then turn that into a Python data structure with `json.loads`, after which you can use standard iteration to filter and map as desired.

If the examples are fully representative, then there are essentially 3 "problems" to resolve in order to make it JSON compliant:

- Curly braces that function as array boundaries should be replaced with square brackets
- Trailing commas (after the last array element) should be removed
- Hexadecimal values, possibly including hyphens, should be quoted (alternatively they could be encoded with a `0x` prefix, but then longer digit sequences have to be broken up into parts, so I'll not go that way).

I'll also assume that:

- opening curly braces that act as array boundaries will always appear at the start of a line (ignoring spacing)
- closing curly braces that act as array boundaries -- possibly accompanied by a trailing comma immediately following it -- will always appear at the end of a line.
- unquoted hexadecimal values will appear at the start of a line (ignoring spacing), with the exception of one opening brace, which can occur before a value.

If all these assumptions are correct, then the following should work:

```
import re
import json

def process(s):
    # replace braces with square brackets
    s = re.sub(r"^(\s*){\n?", r"\1[\n", s, flags=re.M)
    s = re.sub(r"}(,?)$", r"]\1", s, flags=re.M)
    # remove trailing commas (not valid in JSON)
    s = re.sub(r",$(\s+])", r"\1", s, flags=re.M)
    # wrap hex in quotes
    s = re.sub(r'^(\s*)(?=.*[\-a-z])([\w\-]+)', r'\1"\2"', s, flags=re.M)
    return json.loads(s)

with open("stack.json", 'r') as f:
    data = process(f.read())
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works for this examples, and i could make it work for actual data.
I've found pyparsing module, any hints on using that for this task?

Comment: Glad to have been of help! I have no experience with pyparsing though.